# Does Apache Helix support partition split and merge?

Tags: java, scalability, distributed-computing, fault-tolerance, helix

I understand that Apache Helix allows dynamic cluster expansion/shrinkage (e.g, adding/failing/removing physical nodes). However, in the case that a single physical node can not handle a single partition replica, I need to split a partition into two. I understand that we need to pre-estimate the workload, so we can set up sufficient number of partitions up-front. However, as traffic goes up unpredictably, it is almost impossible to do such a pre-estimation. Can anyone tell me whether Helix supports re-partitioning out-of-box? If I need to customize it to add the repartitioning functionality, how large is the effort and how to do it in principle. I want to have a quick estimate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Helix does not support partition splitting/merging out of the box. We could not come up with a generic way to support this without understanding the underlying system.

Having said that, it's possible to build a custom solution using the primitives provided by Helix. If you can provide additional information about your system, I might be able to suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with a high number of (logical) partitions, and assigning each node multiple partitions. When the service needs more resources, add nodes and move some partitions from existing nodes to the new nodes. 
For instance, assuming you'd start with 50 nodes, you'd split the space of your workload to 50000 logical partitions, and assign 1000 partitions to each node. Then when increasing to, say, 75 nodes, redistribute. So it would be 667 partitions per node.
Depending on the actual scenario, you might want to minimize the reallocated partitions, for example using a consistent hashing algorithm.